# Compiling through gcc and using -ltr results in an error, how to fix it?

Tags: c, gcc, arm, cross-compiling, elliptic-curve

Iwant compile the fourQ lib from Microsoft foe ARM-architecture. When I try to link the parts it turns me out an error:

```
FourQ_x64_and_portable>make CC=gcc ARCH=ARM GENERIC=TRUE
gcc -c -O3        -D _ARM_ -D __LINUX__    -D _GENERIC_     ecc_tests.c
gcc -c -O3        -D _ARM_ -D __LINUX__    -D _GENERIC_     FourQ.c
gcc -c -O3        -D _ARM_ -D __LINUX__    -D _GENERIC_     eccp2.c
gcc -c -O3        -D _ARM_ -D __LINUX__    -D _GENERIC_     eccp2_no_endo.c
gcc -c -O3        -D _ARM_ -D __LINUX__    -D _GENERIC_     eccp2_core.c
gcc -c -O3        -D _ARM_ -D __LINUX__    -D _GENERIC_     test_extras.c
gcc -o ecc_test ecc_tests.o FourQ.o eccp2.o eccp2_no_endo.o eccp2_core.o  test_extras.o  -lrt
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lrt
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [ecc_test] Error 1
```

mingw32/5.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lrt

So, does anyone know how to fix it on Win10 with MinGW?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those errors mention that there is a missing lib. In this case "-librt" = "-lrt" is missing. 
So this errors arise. "-l" declares to use a lib, "rt" is the name of the "rt.a" or "rt.ld" lib-file.